# Clipping layers in dataframe with polygon in Python?

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000840

I'm trying to clip layers in a dataframe with a polygon using python and I've done this python script but it's giving this error:

> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import mapping
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
polygon=r'C:\temp\extentPoly.shp'

for layer in mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"", df):
    FL=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer,"_outlayer")
    clipped_fc = env.scratchFolder + os.sep + "_clipped.shp"
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(FL, polygon,clipped_fc)

del layer
del mxd
del df
```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111710/clipping-faster-in-arcgis check the code here, a similar one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Which line returns the error? Maybe you should check if the layer can be converted to a feature layer and clipped using

`if layer.isFeatureLayer:`

2.Besides this, your script will overwrite `clipped_fc` at every iteration. Change the name to something like `clipped_fc = env.scratchFolder + os.sep + layer.name + "_clipped.shp"`. Check that the layers' name is a valid value for naming a shapefile.