# Clipping faster (i.e. in bulk/batch) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, clip

I have 100 different input vector layers and one clip feature vector layer.

I have to clip them 100 times but its a large amount of work.

Is there any Python script (ArcPy) in ArcGIS for Desktop to accelerate my work and avoid the one by one clipping?

Comment: This Q could be merged with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84989/batch-clip-in-modelbuilder-of-arcgis-for-desktop; well the answers could be merged, the Q's come from different places. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple block of code either directly from Python window in ArcGIS or as a Python script or as a custom script tool.

Below is a sample code for a [script tool.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_a_script_tool/001500000006000000/) Just add your vector layers into a map document (.mxd) and specify the clip layer and the output geodatabase.

```
import os, arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

clip_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out_gdb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

mxd_obj = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd_obj):
    arcpy.AddMessage(lyr)
    out_layer = os.path.join(out_gdb,lyr.name)
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(lyr,clip_layer,out_layer)
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, this was the essential kickstart I needed for [ArcGIS desktop map package, with clipping](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132352/arcgis-desktop-map-package-with-clipping).

Comment: @mattwilkie, glad my work helped someone, this is probably the very argument for me to be around on GIS.SE :)

Answer (score 5):

In you case (only one tool), you can simply right click on the clip tool in your toolbox, and launch it as a "batch". See the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000w000000) for more details

Answer (score 5):

You can place all the feature classes within a single dataset then use model builder to clip all at once and output to a new dataset:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The images are nice for instant recognition, "yes, I'm in the right place". The parameters would benefit from being reiterated in the answer body as text; they're almost too small to read.