# ArcGIS desktop map package, with clipping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, map-package

[Package Map (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000q5000000) *almost* does what I want: take everything in my current map, wrap it up in a nice little parcel with all geometry, attributes, labels, symbols, etc. etc. configured just the way that's needed into a single file that can be handed off to someone else or archived as a snapshot in project time.

The one thing the out of the box tool does not do which I need is **clip**. Clip *everything* to dataframe, clip to selected polygon (or graphic), clip to visible area (plus a margin), and *then* apply Package Map magic.

How might this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I built a script for the first half of this: [clip_all_layers.py](https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/blob/master/ArcToolbox/Scripts/clip_all_layers.py), Clips all layers in map to the specified polygon layer. Command line usage:

```
python clip_all_layers.py "path\to\Some map.mxd" path\to\data.gdb\clip_poly path\to\destination.gdb
```

Relative paths are interpreted relative to the mxd, not the current shell folder ([ref](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136826/108)).
There's an example toolbox usage in the Tests folder.

It's adapted from Alex Tereshenkov's work at [Clipping faster (i.e. in bulk/batch) in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111710/clipping-faster-i-e-in-bulk-batch-in-arcgis-for-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can in arcpy.PackageMap_management, there is a parameter called **extent** you can use it to clip map data to the dataframe. e.g. to clip by dataframe use **DISPLAY**...

Have a look at [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q5000000)

Comment: I tried using /extent/ but it no clipping occurred. I think it may mean "include whatever features intersect with /extent/". I'm happy to be proven wrong. Is your experience different?

Comment: to me arcpy.PackageMap_management("C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\Untitled.mxd","C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\Untitled.mpk","CONVERT","CONVERT_ARCSDE",'DISPLAY',"ALL") works fantastic.

Comment: Not for me. I get an intersect selection, not clip; screenshots of my [before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jNwZK.png) and [after](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQnpq.png) (with v10.3).

Comment: It drivied me crazy, why i am getting clipped result though some extra feature -------before https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0zwwqgkqha15n9/1.png?dl=0 and after       https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh8dxrn9gtq7smo/2.png?dl=0

Comment: Per the doc, extent with features does SELECT/EXTRACT. For Rasters it does a clip:  For feature layers, the Extent parameter is used to select the features that will be consolidated. For raster layers, the Extent parameter is used to clip the raster datasets.